# how to handle multiple endpoints in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sap-conversational-ai

I'm developing SAP Conversational AI bot to handle login to sap and product inquire through single webhook.js file which always hits to /login section , I want to **modify this file (presales_assistance_webhook.js) to handle** ,**multiple post support** and cannot use multiple files due to SAP Conversational AI limitation . I'm new to nodejs and need some expert support for this.

//1.login intent: app.post('/login ', (req, res) => {})

//2.product inquiry intent: app.post('/presales', (req, res) => {})

**presales_assistance_webhook.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)


  res.send({
    replies: [{
      type: 'text',
      content: 'Welcome to b1 system !',
    }],
    conversation: {
      memory: {
        key: 'value'
      }
    }
  })
})
app.post('/presales', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)


  res.send({
    replies: [{
      type: 'text',
      content: 'Output ok',
    }],
    conversation: {
      memory: {
        key: 'value'
      }
    }
  })
})

app.post('/errors', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send()
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it well. That code works for me.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/login',getLoginInformations);
app.post('/presales',getPresalesInformations);

function getLoginInformations(req, res) {  
  console.log(req.body) 
  res.send({
    replies: [{
      type: 'text',
      content: 'Welcome to b1 system !'
    }],
    conversation: {
      memory: {
        key: 'value'
      }
    }
  })
}

function getPresalesInformations(req, res) {  
  console.log(req.body) 
  res.send({
    replies: [{
      type: 'text',
      content: 'Output ok'
    }],
    conversation: {
      memory: {
        key: 'value'
      }
    }
  })
} 
app.post('/errors', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send()
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: explicit router did not solve the issue ,@severino will modify the code

Comment: @serverono after I used explicit router , from SAP Conversational AI bot it returned No Result , the modified code worked fine

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058349/6899111) answer you can simply use

```
    app.get(
    ['/test', '/alternative', '/barcus*', '/farcus/:farcus/', '/hoop(|la|lapoo|lul)/poo'],
    function ( request, response ) {

    }
);
```