# Express.js app.get() request gives an error in Postman

Tags: javascript, express

I am new to Express.js and I am using postman for api. When i execute the below code i get all the members from the object

```
// gets all members
app.get('/api/members', (req, res) => {
    res.json(members)
})
```

[postman image for displaying all members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk6X5.png)

but when i try to access single member from the api using the following code i get the 404 error in postman

```
// get single member
app.get('/api/member/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json(members.filter((member) => member.id === parseInt(req.params.id)))
})
```

[postman error message for accessing single user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkwzT.png)

here is the full members object code which is converted to api

```
const members = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'jack',
        email: 'jack@me.com',
        status: 'active'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'sheldon',
        email: 'sheldon@me.com',
        status: 'inactive'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'matt',
        email: 'matt@me.com',
        status: 'active'
    },
]

module.exports = members
```

Someone please explain what the error is...

Answer (score 1):

So your express route is set to `'/api/member/:id'` and you are sending request at `'/api/members/1'` end-point. Try removing 's' from your postman request's url. In simple words, try: `'/api/member/1'`

Comment: or have best of both by using array `['/api/members/:id', '/api/member/:id']`

Comment: Nice catch by @LawrenceCherone :D

Comment: @LawrenceCherone we can use an array of urls for the same endpoin?

Comment: @Ifaruki [yup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350025/express-js-single-routing-handler-for-multiple-routes-in-a-single-line), can use regex too which would make my comment above superfluous

Comment: It's not a good practice because usually, you want a specific end-point. Plus it's against the rest convention policies but of course, you can do it.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan Yeah for sure! never want to be documenting that.. oh also you can use this or this or this